# is accepted or is acceptable?

Tags: tenses

I want to understand structure of sentence.

1. Cash on delivery **is accepted** here.
2. Cash on delivery **is acceptable** here.

Q. What is form of statement 1 (is + accepted) ?
Q. Are both statement true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are true but have slightly different meanings.

The first statement indicates that cash is usable here, it is approved here, accepted and not subject to dispute.

The second statement refers to the fact that cash is not frowned upon, or not allowed, it is acceptably adequate for the purpose.

Comment: What is  usage of   is + past form of verb ?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to provide an adequate answer to that question.

Comment: I got answer : it's "Passive Voice"